# How to Remove line if word exists? (PHP)

Tags: php, cpu-word, line, exists

Hey, I want to remove the whole line if a word exists in it? through PHP?

Example: `hello world, this world rocks`.
What it should do is: if it finds the word `hello` it should remove the whole line.
How can i do that and there could be words in between brackets and inverted commas also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array of lines like so

```
$lines = array(
  'hello world, this world rocks',
  'or possibly not',
  'depending on your viewpoint'
);
```

You can loop through the array and look for the word

```
$keyword = 'hello';
foreach ($lines as &$line) {
  if (stripos($line, $keyword) !== false) {
    //string exists
    $line = '';
  } 
}
```

`int stripos ( string $haystack , string $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )` : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Comment: `substr` is used to extract a portion of a string. I think you mean `strpos` or `strstr`.

Comment: sheesh! I'll forget my underwear next. Yup, I meant `stripos`, got my wires crossed

Comment: hey thanks for the answer John. It worked. the stripos function removed the line... thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
$str = 'Example: hello world, this world rocks.
What it should do is: 
if it finds the word hello it should
remove the whole line. How can i do that and there 
could be words in between brackets and inverted commas also.';

$lines = explode("\n", $str);

foreach($lines as $index => $line) {
   if (strstr($line, 'hello')) {
      unset($lines[$index]);
   }
}

$str = implode("\n", $lines);

var_dump($str);
```

#### Output

```
string(137) "What it should do is: 
remove the whole line. How can i do that and there 
could be words in between brackets and inverted commas also."
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/OoY29N7w).

You said the word could be *could be words in between brackets and inverted commas also* too.

In the case of wanting the word only on its own, or between bracket and quotes, you could replace the `strstr()` with this...

```
preg_match('/\b["(]?hello["(]?\b/', $str);
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/CcRh8).

I assumed by brackets you meant parenthesis and inverted commas you meant double quotes.

You could also use a regex in multiline mode, however it won't be as obvious at first glance what this code does...

```
$str = trim(preg_replace('/^.*\b["(]?hello["(]?\b.*\n?/m', '', $str));
```

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378163).

Comment: hey alex... thanks for the answer... the preg_replace function removes the word, but fails to remove the whole line? can u tell me y is this happening? and i'm only using the preg_replace function. i'm not using the above code you put. can u tell me also how to combine both of those or any other way, as i can remove the whole line.

Comment: @Arjun It is not good form to accept one answer and then the other (figure out exactly which one best solves your issue). Don't worry about it now, but remember it for next time.

Comment: ok sorry... actually i'm bit new to stackoverflow... i'll remember it... :D thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Nice and simple:

```
$string = "hello world, this world rocks"; //our string
if(strpos($string, "hello") !== FALSE) //if the word exists (we check for false in case word is at position 0)
{
  $string = ''; //empty the string.
}
```