# Can I use preg_replace to strip the trailing \n in multiline mode?

Tags: php, regex

[I just answered a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377798/how-to-remove-line-if-word-exists-php/5377871#5377871), which has left me asking my own question.

Basically, the OP wanted any line to be removed if it contained a string. Here is a regex I came up with...

```
$str = preg_replace('/^.*\b["(]?hello["(]?\b.*$/m', '', $str);
```

It works great, but because `$` matches before the trailing `\n`, they remain when replaced and there are blank lines, e.g.

```
string(90) "
What it shouldhello do is:


could be words in between brackets and inverted commas also."
```

I can't use `\z` because I'm in multiline mode (at least that is what I think).

If I use `s` modifier, the `.` become too greedy and don't work across the newlines.

I have tried a few things (such as `[^\n]` and `[\s\S]`), and now I am stumped.

How can I match that trailing `\n` here so it is removed with the replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use \n instead of $.

```
$str = preg_replace('/^.*\b["(]?hello["(]?\b.*\n/m', '', $str);
```

This misses the last line if it had hello in it, so here's a step further.

```
$str = preg_replace('/^.*\b["(]?hello["(]?\b.*(\n|$)/m', '', $str);
```

The issue now is that the last line is removed, but there is still a \n character (similar issue you're already having).

*Note: I'm not a regular expression expert at all, just can usually do enough for my needs.*

Comment: Except this will miss the last line if it has hello in it :S

Answer (score 1):

I feel pretty silly for not figuring this one out, but I used [Jacob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378163/can-i-use-preg-replace-to-strip-the-trailing-n-in-multiline-mode/5378192#5378192) as a basis...

```
$str = preg_replace('/^.*\b["(]?hello["(]?\b.*\n?/m', '', $str);
```

Looks like I was just *too keen* to use the end of line anchor.

This one allows for the optional `\n` at the end. It also leaves a `\n` at the end of the last non matched line, but I could always then `trim($str)`.

Comment: Has the same issue as mine, since my edit... the last line :S

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^.*?\b["(]?hello["(]?\b.*?$/s', '', $str);
```

`.*?` makes it non-greedy.

Comment: That didn't work sorry, it just replaced the whole string with an empty string.